# Express app CPU peaks

Tags: performance, node.js

I have a quite simple, RESTful server that basically adds/gets data from the DB via mongoose client. The server is an amazon micro instance and what I find strange is that, checking my server stats, it sometimes shows peaks of 50% CPU usage with EXTREMELY low concurrency - I'm talking about something like no more than 10 users). Have a look at the picture to get the idea.

[image: cpu usage]

Please ignore the time as it is another time-zone.

Only problem I can think of is that I am not writing correct "node.js" callback codes. This is my main model, which functions get called by the routee.

```
var _         = require('underscore'),
    mongoose  = require('mongoose'),
    sanitize  = require('validator').sanitize,
    Validator = require('validator').Validator,
    redis     = require('../models/reds'),
    v         = new Validator();

v.error = function(msg){
  return false;
};

var itemSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  adm:  { type: String },
  url:  { type: String, required: true },
  desc: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
  tags: { type: [String] },
}, { autoIndex: false }).index({ tags: 1 });

var Male   = mongoose.model('Male', itemSchema),
    Female = mongoose.model('Female', itemSchema);

var idFromTime = function(time){
  var createId = function(int){ return mongoose.Types.ObjectId(int + '0000000000000000') };

  if(!time)
    return createId(Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000).toString(16));
    else return createId(time);
};

exports.getPhotos = function(options, next){
  var query,
      parameters = {},
      tags = [];

  if( v.validate(options.tags).is(/^[-\sa-z]+$/) && options.tags != 'undefined' ){
    tags = options.tags.split(' ');
    parameters['tags'] = { '$all': tags };
  }

  if(options.time && options.time.length == 8 && options.time.match(/[0-9a-f]+/))
    parameters['_id'] = { '$lt': idFromTime(options.time) };
    else parameters['_id'] = { '$lt': idFromTime() };

  if(options.female == true || options.male == false)      query = Female.find(parameters);
  else if(options.male == true || options.female == false) query = Male.find(parameters); 

  query
    .limit(29)
    .sort('-_id')
    .select('url desc')
    .exec(function(err, items) { next(err, items) });
};

exports.addPhoto = function(options, next){
  var photo,
      parameters,
      tags = [];

  if(
    options.desc != 'undefined' &&
    v.validate(options.desc).len(2, 100) &&
    v.validate(options.url).isUrl() &&
    v.validate(options.tags).is(/^[-\sa-z]+$/) ){
      tags = options.tags.split(' ');
      tags = _.compact(tags)
      tags = _.uniq(tags);

      parameters = {
        adm:  options.admin,
        url:  options.url,
        desc: options.desc,
        tags: tags,
      };
  } else {
    next(true);
    return false;
  }

  if(options.female == true || options.male == false)      photo = new Female(parameters);
  else if(options.male == true || options.female == false) photo = new Male(parameters);

  photo.save(function(err, photo){
    next(err, photo);
  });
};

exports.getComments = function(id, next){
  redis.lrange(id, 0, -1, function(err, list){
    next(err, list);
  });
};

exports.setComment = function(id, text, next){
  if(!text || 0 === text.length) {
    next(true);
  } else{
    redis.multi()
      .lpush(id, text)
      .ltrim(id, 0, 19)
      .expire(id, 2628000)
      .exec(function(err, reply){
        if(!err)
          next(false);
          else next(true);
      });
  }
}
```

I have mongodb & redis also running on the server, and to display the only single page in my website I make use of both jade & stylus.

Is there any performance related problem with my code or I can rest assured that it is just the micro instance not being as performant as I imagined?

Comment: Is there anything to suggest that it's the Express app that's using all that CPU, and not some other process?

Comment: The only thing that might suggest me it's the app, is the fact that the code might be written badly. Once I am sure that it is ok, I can go further and trace the problem.

Comment: At first glance it looks okay, but it's impossible to give you any assurances that it's not going to be your app (also you didn't post it in its entirety). Since it seems to be peaking around the same time each day (~6AM), I suspect a cron job or something.

Comment: there is no cron job at all.. it is a "clean" ubuntu server installation. The peaks are the users connecting.